# Why can I do prime decomposition if m contains several primes but not if it contains just one prime?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Why can I $\ {2^{32}\pmod {30} }$ decomposite in

$x \equiv{2^{32}\pmod {5} }$

$x \equiv{2^{32}\pmod {3} }$

$x \equiv{2^{32}\pmod {2} }$

$\ {2^{32}\pmod {30} = x }$

but not $\ {2^{32}\pmod {25} }$ in

$x \equiv{2^{32}\pmod {5} }$ ?

$\ {2^{32}\pmod {25} ≠ x }$

Both m are decomposite into primes.

Thanks in advance. I appreciate your help.

Comment: What's the question?   $2^{32}\equiv 21\pmod {25}$.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @lulu I updated the post now. I can compute $ 2^{32} \pmod {30}  $ with prime decomposition of m and the associated equation. But with  $ 2^{32} \pmod {25}  $ this is not possible, because 25 contains only one prime number. Why is that so?

Comment: The Chinese REmainder theorem tells you (informally speaking) that all the information regarding a congruence $\pmod {mn}$ is contained in the congruences $\pmod m,\pmod n$ *if* $\gcd(m,n)=1$.   With $25$ you can't use $25=5\times 5$ as $\]gcd(5,5)>1$.

Comment: $2^{32} \equiv x \pmod{30} \iff 30 ~|~ [2^{32} - x] \iff \{2 ~|~ [2^{32} - x] \wedge 3 ~|~ [2^{32} - x] \wedge 5 ~|~ [2^{32} - x]\}.$

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks. I got it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Chinese remainder theorem only allows you to decompose a composite modulus in a modular equation into *prime powers*, not single primes.

It is still possible to extend a solution modulo a prime $p$ to one modulo $p^2,p^3\dots$ but this is [Hensel lifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel_lifting), not the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ElMatador Consider accepting an answer if you've no further questions.